# What exactly is CPU load if instructions are executed one at a time?

Tags: cpu, scheduling, cpu-usage, scheduler

I know this question has been asked many times in many different manners, but it's still not clear for me what the CPU load % means.

I'll start explaining how I perceive the concepts now (of course, I might, and sure will, be wrong):

- A CPU core can only execute one instruction at a time. It will not execute the next instruction until it finishes executing the current one.
- Suppose your box has one single CPU with one single core. Parallel computing is hence not possible. Your OS's scheduler will pick up a process, set the IP to the entry point, and send that instruction to the CPU. It won't move to the next instruction until the CPU finishes executing the current instruction. After a certain amount of time it will switch to another process, and so on. But it will never switch to another process if the CPU is currently executing an instruction. It will wait until the CPU becomes free to switch to another process. Since you only have one single core, you can't have two processes executing simultaneously.
- I/O is expensive. Whenever a process wants to read a file from the disk, it has to wait until the disk accomplishes its task, and the current process can't execute its next instruction until then. The CPU is not doing anything while the disk is working, and so our OS will switch to another process until the disk finishes its job in order not to waste time.

Following these principles, I've come myself to the conclusion that CPU load at a given time can only be one of the following two values:

- 0% - Idle. CPU is doing nothing at all.
- 100% - Busy. CPU is currently executing an instruction.

This is obviously false as taskmgr reports %1, 12%, 15%, 50%, etc. CPU usage values.

- What does it mean that a given process, at a given time, is utilizing 1% of a given CPU core (as reported by taskmgr)? While that given process is executing, what happens with the 99%?
- What does it mean that the overall CPU usage is 19% (as reported by Rainmeter at the moment)?

Comment: "*A CPU core can only execute one instruction at a time. It will not execute the next instruction until it finishes executing the current one.*" This is not true. Punch "superscalar" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the task manager on Windows there is Idle process, that does exactly that, it just shows amount of cycles not doing anything useful. Yes, CPU is always busy, but it might be just running in a loop waiting for useful things to come.

> Since you only have one single core, you can't have two processes
>   executing simultaneously.

This is not really true. Yes, true parallelism is not possible with single core, but you can create illusion of one with [preemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29). Yes, it is impossible to interrupt instruction, but it is not a problem because most of the instructions require tiny amount of time to finish. OS shares time with time slices, which are significantly longer than execution time of single instruction.

```
What does it mean that a given process, at a given time, is utilizing 1% of a given CPU core
```

Most of the time applications are not doing anything useful. Think of application that waits for user to click a button to start processing something. This app doesn't need CPU, so it sleeps most of the time, or every time it gets time slice it just goes into sleep (see [event loop in Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)). `GetMessage` is blocking, so it means that thread will sleep until message arrives. So what CPU load really means? So imagine the app receives some events or data to do things, it will do operations instead of sleeping. So if it utilizes `X%` of CPU means that over sampling period of time that app used `X%` of CPU time. CPU time usage is average metric.

**PS:** To summarize concept of CPU load, think of speed (in terms of physics). There are instantaneous and average speeds, so speaking of CPU load, there also are instantaneous and average measurements. Instantaneous is always equal to either 0% or 100%, because at some point of time process either uses CPU or not. If process used 100% of CPU in the course of 250ms and didn't use for next 750ms then we can say that process loaded CPU for 25% with sampling period of 1 second (*average* measurement can only be applied with certain sampling period).

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

> A single-core CPU is like a single lane of traffic. Imagine you are a bridge operator ... sometimes your bridge is so busy there are cars lined up to cross. You want to let folks know how traffic is moving on your bridge. A decent metric would be how many cars are waiting at a particular time. If no cars are waiting, incoming drivers know they can drive across right away. If cars are backed up, drivers know they're in for delays.
>
> This is basically what CPU load is. "Cars" are processes using a slice of CPU time ("crossing the bridge") or queued up to use the CPU. **Unix refers to this as the run-queue length: the sum of the number of processes that are currently running plus the number that are waiting (queued) to run.**

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)

Comment: How does it answer question about idle states?

Comment: Yes, the CPU can (theoretically) be idle.